# How to send continuous stream of frames to server most efficiently

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am trying to send frames from a local camera (raspberry pi camera, but could also be my laptop's webcam) to a Google cloud instance, on which I am running AI processing of the frames.

I am managing to send frames captured through opencv via http (i.e. tcp??) and receiving them on a flask server. When the flask server is running locally I can get good fps (50+ fps for image size 640x480), however once I send the frames to a flask app on the google instance the fps drop drastically to ~5fps.

How I currently send frames:

```
while True:
        frame = vs.read() #Separate thread, using cv2 to get the frame

        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        imgdata = jpeg.tobytes()
        response = requests.post(
            url='http://<IP address of google instance>:<port>',
            data= imgdata,
            headers={'content-type':'image/jpeg'},
            )
```

I see two problems with this:
1 - using tcp means I am slower than udp protocol, however udp is limited in byte size. Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems very complex to send truncated frames and put them back together on the server..
2 - Even if I had udp working, there is no compression of frames, so I will never reach an efficient transfer

I expect the answer to be something like using ffmpeg, but so far I only figured out how to stream frames on a local port with ffmpeg, I do not know if it is possible to send frames to a remote server.

Any recommendations on the best way forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct choice of protocol for your case is TCP. UDP does not guarantee that the data would arrive in the correct order and intact. UDP would not be faster than TCP in your case (if you would ensure that the data is intact and in order in your code).

You are already compressing your images by converting them to jpg. Additional compression would be really inefficient. Both TCP and UDP do not compress data in transfer.

I believe that right now you are somewhat limited by `requests` library and encoding the data into HTTP protocol. You should consider using pure TCP, without the overhead of HTTP. This could be done via `socket` module in the standard python library. However you would probably still have low performance, because you do not have the inter-frame compression and only using the intra-frame compression. You would need to consider using the ffmpeg to compress the data from your camera and send the stream over TCP with your program or by using [ffmpeg's point 2 point streaming](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Pointtopointstreaming).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, very helpful. I'm surprised TCP is not slower, but fine by me since it seems easier :) Ffmpeg is still a bit of a blackbox that I am starting to look into, but if I need to start using it anyway, is it maybe even simpler and more efficient to just use ffmpeg from command line to stream frames to my server then (if that's feasible)? Or is it necessary to combine it with 'socket' and 'os.sendfile' to send to the server?

Comment: Network performance is a complex subject. Strictly speaking, you can send data over UDP as fast as your network card can. The problems arrive when your barrage of data creates congestion on the network and your messages are disregarded by providers. TCP is slower to set-up the connection and it limits the speed of transfer, but it operates near the maximal speed possible by the network at the moment. Also it takes care of integrity control, retransmitting lost data, etc. In short UDP offers lower latency, but higher error rate (missed/corrupted data). TCP offers higher latency and reliability.

Comment: As for ffmpeg, quick cursory google search brought this: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Pointtopointstreaming ffmpeg allows send and receive streams via udp or tcp.